# How to display last 3 posts (recent posts) in a static page?

Tags: pages, recent-posts

I would like to implement something like "recent posts" in a static page:

http://themes.codehunk.me/insignio/ (at the footer)

How I would be able to do this without a widget?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I usually use this approach:

**wrong approach**

```
<?php query_posts( array(
   'category_name' => 'news',
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
)); ?>

<?php if( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

   <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

With the help of @swissspidy **the correct way** is this one:

```
<?php 
   // the query
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'category_name' => 'news',
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
   )); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See [@codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for more info.

Comment: I like to reference to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/12404 in order to show why using `query_posts()` is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

It kind of depends on what you're going for.  If you want to do a "page of posts" -- other words, create a new page template file -- you can create a secondary loop on that page.

[The codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts) has an example of this and here's another, very stripped down example.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page of Posts
*/
get_header(); 
?>

<?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); /* start main loop */ ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php
        /* Start Secondary Loop */
        $other_posts = new WP_Query( /*maybe some args here? */ );
        while( $others_posts->have_posts() ): $other_posts->the_post(); 
    ?>
        You can do anything you would in the main loop here and it will
        apply to the secondary loop's posts
    <?php 
        endwhile; /* end secondary loop */ 
        wp_reset_postdata(); /* Restore the original queried page to the $post variable */
    ?>

<?php endwhile; /* End the main loop */ ?>
```

If you're looking for something that you can drop into any page, the best solution would be a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). You would need to create a shortcode that fetches several posts and returns them in a list (or whatever you want). An example:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse36453_register_shortcode' );
/**
 * Registers the shortcode with add_shortcode so WP knows about it.
 */
function wpse36453_register_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode( 'wpse36453_posts', 'wpse36453_shortcode_cb' );
}

/**
 * The call back function for the shortcode. Returns our list of posts.
 */
function wpse36453_shortcode_cb( $args )
{
    // get the posts
    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts'   => 3
        )
    );

    // No posts? run away!
    if( empty( $posts ) ) return '';

    /**
     * Loop through each post, getting what we need and appending it to 
     * the variable we'll send out
     */ 
    $out = '<ul>';
    foreach( $posts as $post )
    {
        $out .= sprintf( 
            '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>',
            get_permalink( $post ),
            esc_attr( $post->post_title ),
            esc_html( $post->post_title )
        );
    }
    $out .= '</ul>';
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Can I put this into header.php or should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: The first example can go anywhere in your theme.  The second, shortcode, example should go in `functions.php`

Comment: the first block of code doesn't have a to loop over 3 posts

Answer (score 3):

There's a guide for this precise case at the wordpress codex. See it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Latest_posts_ordered_by_title):
I paste the code here because it's quite short, for more information go to the wordpress.org site.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
    <div>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
        <br />
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress provides a function for that kind of request: [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

> query_posts() is the easiest way to alter the default query that
>   WordPress uses to display posts. Use query_posts() to display
>   different posts than those that would normally show up at a specific
>   URL.
>
> For example, on the homepage, you would normally see the latest 10
>   posts. If you want to show only 5 posts (and don't care about
>   pagination), you can use query_posts() like so:
>
> > query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );

Once you've performed the query, you can display the posts the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); 
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();?>
<?php /*html in here etc*/ the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile;wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: its code that answers the question - How to display last 3 posts (recent posts) in a static page?  Would it help you if I said - "I usually use this approach:"?